# Firebase Cloud Functions - Send Notification user when they are online again?

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using fcm to send user notification and its triggedred by writing data to firebase database. But when user is offline notification send but never received and user cannot see it after they back online. How to send notification in all conditions.

Example: If user online send message normally but if user offline wait until user online and send them. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use FCM and instead put the message in a database.  Query the database when they go online.

Comment: @DougStevenson but when i use your system user have to launch app. But i wanna show notifications without launching app like facebook or instagram.

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense to me.  If the user never launches their app, how does your app know they're "online"?  That's not the way mobile apps work.  The OS will kill the app when the user isn't using it, and it can't know anything about their "online" status.

Comment: @DougStevenson when i say online i mean their device is connected to internet Not online like whatsapp

Comment: You should just send a message normally and expect that the system will deliver it at the soonest possible moment, within the constraints of the system.

Comment: @DougStevenson Oh so you say firebase cloud messaging alredy support what i want. Am i right? what is notification life span? After how many time notificaiton expires itself? If its still not delievered?

Comment: @DougStevenson I found the answer thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to documents firebase cloud messaging already support what i want.

> If the device is not connected to FCM, the message is stored until a
>   connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules).
>   When a connection is established, FCM delivers all pending messages to
>   the device. If the device never gets connected again (for instance, if
>   it was factory reset), the message eventually times out and is
>   discarded from FCM storage. The default timeout is four weeks, unless
>   the time_to_live flag is set.

So FCM service wait until client device connected again.And sen notification when cliend connected. But if user hasnt connected for four weeks message deletes itself and never sent.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl